# Convert only a particular div of an HTML page by its id into PDF

Tags: javascript, jquery, pdf, jspdf

I am converting a particular div of an HTML page by its id into pdf with CSS but it is converting the contents of div which is currently visible but my content is more. i have to scroll then print but its only print which is currently visible and print black which is not visible div part.

```
<div id='invoice'>Contents Here..</div>
<a id="cmd" href="javascript:genPDF()">Download PDF</a

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/0.9.0rc1/jspdf.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.3.5/jspdf.debug.js"></script>
<script src="html2canvas.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#cmd').on('click', function() {
    var pdf = new jsPDF('p', 'pt', 'letter');

    pdf.addHTML($('#invoice')[0], function() {
        pdf.save('order_report.pdf');
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: you can use this free plugin.

http://rawgit.com/MrRio/jsPDF/master/

Comment: @SharifurRobin its working fine but only not visible div contents convert as black screen others contents are perfect

Comment: I recommend trying http://pdfmake.org/. From my experience, jsPDF is very buggy.